# Synchronise when an instance of Server 2008 is brought up in Amazon

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, files

What is built into Windows server to allow the replication of files from a "Master" folder on the main server to be copied over to the instance that was just CREATED in the amazon control panel?

The key point here is that this is a newly created instance with no prior knowledge of its hostname/ip etc although this could be a pre-configured image.

It will need to be automatically able to do a two way sync with the master server folder

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx) script.